# Adjust border width of image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, width, border

```js
var images = document.getElementById("facilityThumbNail").getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.cursor = 'hand';
    this.style.borderColor = 'red';
    // this.style.border ? ? ? ? ?
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="facilityThumbNail">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" />
</div>
```

Just wondering if someone can please tell me how I can adjust the width of border for this image by advising what the attribute is?  It's not width...

Comment: Width of the border, `borderWidth`? Also, you may need to set a border style before you can see the border.

Comment: I edited your question to show the code in a runnable snippet. Please feel free to correct anything I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do specify the `borderStyle` and `borderWidth`

```js
var images = document.getElementById("facilityThumbNail").getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.cursor = 'hand';
    this.style.borderWidth = '10px';
    this.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    this.style.borderColor = 'red';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="facilityThumbNail">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" />
</div>
```